# "file_get_contents(http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/config/xxx.ini): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! "

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I got this error message when trying to send form data post request via POST method.

```
"file_get_contents(http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/config/xxx.ini): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! "
```

Laravel code

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $options = [
                'form_params' => [
                    'service_id' =>  $id,
                    'email' => auth()->user()->email
                ],
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'name'     => 'file',
                        'contents' => file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/config/'.$service->config, 'r' ),
                        'filename' => $service->config
                    ]
                ]
            ];
            $response = $client->post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/run', $options);
```

By the way, the file exist if I view at URL. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making an http request to read the file, use the `storage_path` helper:

```
'contents' => file_get_contents(storage_path('config/'.$service->config, 'r' )),
```